# When to await a dynamically invoked method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, async-await

My code does this to invoke a registered method when a network requests comes in. It's part of an RPC system.

```
Delegate method;
object result = method.DynamicInvoke(args);
```

When the method returns a value, everything is good. But when it returns something awaitable, I'm not interested in trying to give that awaitable something back to the network caller. They won't make any use of it, and it's probably not transferrable anyway. Instead I need to wait for it and then return the actual result.

I could just check if the method's return type is something like a `Task`. Or a `Task<T>`. Is that enough? Can't there be other awaitable things in the universe? How would I test for the type `Task`? I mean I can't just do something like this:

```
method.Method.ReturnType is Task
```

It won't be true. And there's also no:

```
method.Method.ReturnType.IsAwaitable
```

I acknowledge that I won't be able to wait for an `async void` method. But anything else, eventually awaitable, should be awaited.

Comment: It could be a lot more complex, if you really want to your code to work for all cases. I don't know the exact rules, so I won't post it as an answer, but an object is awaitable if it has a method called `GetAwaiter` and if the return value of that method is a type that looks similar to a `TaskAwaiter`.

Comment: @Dirk, a type does not need to have a `GetAwaiter` method to be awaitable. The `GetAwaiter` method can be an extension method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is awaitable is something the the compiler knows. You need to pin it down to the types you know how to handle.

Try something like this:

```
object result = null;
if (method.Method.ReturnType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Task)))
{
    if (method.Method.ReturnType.IsConstructedGenericType)
    {
        dynamic tmp = method.DynamicInvoke(args);
        result = tmp.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    else
    {
        (method.DynamicInvoke(args) as Task).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
else
{
    result = method.DynamicInvoke(args);
}
```